# Name a good guide for the implementation of an STL compatible sequence container)

Tags: c++, stl

I'd like to implement a sequence container with the bells and whistles required for an STL class - for example, my own deque class that can use all of the STL algorithms and utilities that the normal deque class could use.  I'm aware all the STL components and how they work, but I'd definitely miss alot trying to do this on my own.

Does anyone know a good tutorial or reference/checklist that I could use for this purpose?  I'm trying to reinforce the mechanisms in my mind by making one of these classes.

PS - I'm just looking for a link with the information that I need and a half-sentence description, I don't need a discussion of what is best and why as long as the information is there :)

Comment: might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6306231/write-c-container-that-fits-neatly-into-stl

Comment: Huh, good call.  I didn't see that one when I searched :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A container must implement a series of **Concepts**. 
A comprehensive list can be found here:
http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Container.html

Simply implement the requirements there, and you got yourself a container.

Comment: The SGI link is no longer valid.