# Ammending a struct

Tags: c++, struct

I have a struct that is filled with vectors.

```
struct structtype{

vector<double> vec1;
vector<double> vec2;
vector<int> vec3;

};
```

I want to be able to take the specific elements from one struct and add them to another. Sort of like

```
structtype myStructA

myStructA.add(myStructB.at(i))
```

so I'm building `myStructA` out of specific elements of `myStructB`. I'm wondering if within the definition of `structtype` I can just include something like..

```
struct structtype{

vector<double> vec1;
vector<double> vec2;
vector<int> vec3;

void Add(structtype myStructtoAdd, int i){
vec1.push_back(myStructtoAdd.vec1.at(i));
vec2.push_back(myStructtoAdd.vec2.at(i));
vec3.push_back(myStructtoAdd.vec3.at(i));
};


};
```

Will this work? And regardless is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Maybe you want a vector of structs (of single variables), instead of a struct of vectors.

Comment: Agree with @deviantfan. The code suggests that all 3 vectors have the same size, and share the same index `int i`. That said, this is only a small part of the program. If other parts operate on one vector at a time, then a structure of vectors is reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It will work, because in c++ `struct` is very simmilar to `class`, and they support methods. The difference lies in accessibility of members by default - in `class` they're private, and in `struct` they're public. It also applies to inheritance - struct inherits publicly and class - privately (by default - it's still posiblle in both cases to add a desired access specifier)

Comment: _"`struct` is very simmilar to `class`"_ For the avoidance of doubt, it's because both keywords define a class. I'm not sure what any of this has to do with the question, though.

Comment: I guess I hastily assumed it was a typical question for someone who already knows some oop language without stucts (eg. java), thus is familiar with classes, and now learning c++. Thus comparing the two made sense for me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this will work.

About the refinement of this code:

Since you need adding element `i` from one structure to another, probably you may need any other operations over such element, so it looks sensible to define a struct for it, and a retrieving operator:

```
struct element
{
    double f1, f2;
    int f3;
}

element& structtype::operator [] (int i)
{
    return {vec1[i], vec2[i], vec3[i]};
}

const element& structtype::operator [] (int i) const
{
    return {vec1[i], vec2[i], vec3[i]};
}
```

After implementation of these operation you probably may store `element` somewhere else, not only in the `structtype`, which means that `push_back` operation with `element` argument would be useful:

```
void push_back(const element& e)
{
    vec1.push_back(e.f1);
    vec2.push_back(e.f2);
    vec3.push_back(e.f3);
}
```

Also, given that the `structtype` class behaves like a container, it may be useful to implement some other features typical STL containers provide, like iterators. A good guide for STL-like containers implementation is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6306231/write-c-container-that-fits-neatly-into-stl).

Or, as a second option, you may just use `std::vector<element>`, which already implements all of these features.

If its functionality is not enough for you, you may extend it creating a new class which inherites the implementation of `std::vector`. A standard way of doing it is using a `private` inheritance, like this:

```
class structtype : private std::vector<element>
{
public:
    /// Write such lines for all members of std::vector which you would like to have
    using std::vector<element>::size(); 
    ...
    /// Write some your own methods
    std::vector<double> get_vec1() const;
}
```